# Display Glassfish user Login Name in a Google GWT Application

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, gwt, glassfish

I have a Google GWT .war application deployed to Glassfish v3.1.  Glassfish will require a login username and password to access the app.  I am trying to capture the username and display it in the Google GWT app.  Is there a way to do this with a web service or some other method?

Or would it be easier to create a login screen with GWT?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JAAS to authenticate user in container you can create GWT RPC service (extending RemoteServiceServlet) and retrieve username from http request by calling:

```
HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
String username = request.getRemoteUser();
```

Then you can return username from service and display it inside GWT app.

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to use your code to capture the login and this to setup Glassfish and JAAS: http://www.developinjava.com/securing-a-web-application-on-glassfish-using-jaas.html

Comment: You could also use a "dynamic host page" to avoid the GWT-RPC round-trip: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/dynamic_host_page.html